# Python function generator(?), factory(?) not behaving as expected

Tags: python, generator, factory

Not sure if this is called a generator, a factory or something else, but it's not doing what I would expect.

```
d = {}

for i in range(10):
    def func():
        print i
    d[i]=func

print d

for f in d:
    d[f]()
```

This outputs:

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

But I was expecting:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I want to store the current state of func at each step of the for loop, but it seems that the dictionary is getting a reference(?) to the function.  How do I stop this?

Also, if it is storing a reference to the function, I would epect this to print out 'overridden', but it still prints all 9s.  Why is that?

```
d = {}

for i in range(10):
    def func():
        print i
    d[i]=func

print d

def func():
    print 'overridden'

for f in d:
d[f]()
```

Thanks!

Comment: The usual solution is to force the capture with a default value like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2295372/5014455)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to apply that.  I have tried adding `x = i`  in the function but it is the same result.  Can you explain what this does? `lambda a,i=i: i+a`  I have only seen lambda like `lambda x: x+1`

Comment: It uses a default value. The only line you need to change is `def func():` to `def func(i=i):`

Comment: Wow, yeah that worked!  Thank you.  Why does this work though?  I now understand that using a default parameter forces it to capture the current value, but is there a reason why?  Is this behavior used elsewhere in python or is this just a one off way to do this?

Comment: Because default values are bound at function definition time. It's the reason [default mutable arguments bite newbies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). Since closures are lexically scoped in Python, `i` refers to whatever the name `i` refers to *in the scope that `i` has when it was defined*. Using a default value is a trick to force the scope to be local. So, just for fun try `i = 'hey'` and then `d[f]()` when you don't use the default value.

Comment: That is quite a bit to digest.  Thank you!